# packrat R taking forever to install packages

Tags: r, packrat

I need to use `packrat` in order to create a sort of virtual environment for R. I run these few lines

```
mywd<-getwd()
packrat::init(mywd)
packrat::set_opts(auto.snapshot=TRUE)
```

And everything works fine as R output show

```
Initializing packrat project in directory:
- "C:/Users/marco.fumagalli/TEST_PACKRAT"

Adding these packages to packrat:
            _        
    packrat   0.4.9-3

Fetching sources for packrat (0.4.9-3) ... OK (CRAN current)
Snapshot written to "C:/Users/marco.fumagalli/TEST_PACKRAT/packrat/packrat.lock"
Installing packrat (0.4.9-3) ... 
    OK (downloaded binary)
Initialization complete!

Restarting R session...
```

Then I try to install `lubridate` package with `install.packages`. Package has few dependencies ( `magrittr`, `stringi` , `stringr`, `Rcpp` and `glue`) and it's taking more than 20 minutes to install everything, which it seems quite unusual.

These are basic info of my session

```
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
```

Comment: I am also having trouble with this. Any luck so far?

Comment: Nope. I will never use again packrat in my life. I turn to checkpoint package

Comment: is it building the packages from source (I think it does with packrat..), if so then it might take a long time because a bunch of C++ code is being compiled.

Comment: Same problem here. Any updates?

Comment: Nope I gave up.